# Fscanf Doesn't Take Inputs properly

Tags: c, input, output, scanf, filereader

I'm trying to take inputs with `fscanf` and to give output to another file but `fscanf` doesn't give the input it should give.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *a;
    FILE *b;
    int i;
    int played_matches, points, goaldif, ranking;
    int wins, draws, losses, goals_scored, goals_against;
    char team[18];
    a = fopen("source.docx", "r");
    b = fopen("aim.doc", "w");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(a, "%d %s %d %d %d %d %d", &ranking, &team, &wins, &draws, &losses, &goals_scored, &goals_against);         
        played_matches = wins + draws + losses;
        points = (3 * wins) + draws;
        goaldif = goals_scored - goals_against;
        fprintf(b, "%d %s %d %d %d ", ranking, team, played_matches, points, goaldif);
    }

    fclose(a);
    fclose(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: &team should be just team

Comment: Turn on more warnings when compiling. [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8cddh7Par)

Comment: What value does `fscanf` return? the code hasn't checked that it is `7`. Note that if a team name has two words it will fail, and also if the `team` buffer overflows.

Comment: Please add a sample of input and incorrect output.

Comment: Why does your plain text file have a `.docx` extension?

Comment: If the file is really a `.docx`, then you need to find a copy of the docx specification before you can even think about reading it with a C program. Or, the simple thing to do is copy/paste the numbers into a plain text file `.txt`. Make sure that it's a **plain** text file, not a rich text file.

Comment: The output file is also going to be a plain text file, so the correct name is **"aim.txt"**. Calling it "aim.doc" won't make it a doc file. Call it what it really is to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *a;
    FILE *b;
    int i;
    int played_matches, points, goaldif, ranking;
    int wins, draws, losses, goals_scored, goals_against;
    char team[18];
    a = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    b = fopen("aim.txt", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(a, "%d %s %d %d %d %d %d", &ranking, team, &wins, &draws, &losses, &goals_scored, &goals_against);
        played_matches = wins + draws + losses;
        points = (3 * wins) + draws;
        goaldif = goals_scored - goals_against;
        fprintf(b, "%d %s %d %d %d \n", ranking, team, played_matches, points, goaldif);
    }

    fclose(a);
    fclose(b);
    return 0;
}
```

& is for integer values.

Comment: You should also *always* check the return value of any `*scanf()` function. Your input might be malformed, resulting in you working with uninitialized variables.